# Vertically align two rows of legend key and text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have this dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(somethingthatisverylong = c("aaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"), 
                 col2 = c("b", "d"), 
                 col3 = c(1, 2), 
                 col4 = c(1, 2))
```

And generated this `ggplot` graph with two rows of legend:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(col3, col4, color = somethingthatisverylong, shape = col2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.box = "vertical", legend.box.just = "left", legend.text.align = 0)
```

[image: no_padding]

However, the legend keys and labels were not aligned vertically.

I generated my desired graph by manually adding white spaces as paddings to `scale_shape_discrete(name, label)`, which is obviously not ideal.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(col3, col4, color = somethingthatisverylong, shape = col2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "col2                                ", 
                       label = c("b          ", "d")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        legend.box = "vertical", 
        legend.box.just = "left", 
        legend.text.align = 0, 
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "cm"))
```

[image: space_padding]

Is there any smarter way to align them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's curiously tricky! I find that special legend designs are a common question here. My thoughts about that in general:

1. I generally hope for the OPs that such design ideas are rather the exception and they will only need this for one or two figures. This is because as a rule of thumb, the fancier your legend design is, the more difficult becomes automation. It's much easier to do some dirty hacking for one specific figure only.
2. Usually the most straight forward way for any fancy legend is to create a fake legend and stitch it to the first plot, either with custom annotation or with a package like cowplot or patchwork.
3. There is, of course, always the dark side, i.e., tumbling down the grob path. I am afraid of this, it is too powerful for me.
4. My preferred option would be to re-consider the visualisation. Do you really need a legend? Have you considered shortening of your labels, or direct labelling instead? Maybe you can use other plot elements to guide the reader better.

To the problem. There are two distinct problems.

1. Aligning the legend titles
2. Aligning the legend keys.

I like your solution with the padding, and this can be automated. I have made your example a bit more interesting by using two different lengths of your unique aesthetic values. You will need to use a mono-spaced font such as Courier for optimal results. You can either replace the original data values (or create new columns), which is my approach in the code below, or you could use a (named) vector in `scale_manual`.

This is "easy-ish" for the variable values (i.e. legend text), but it would become rather messy for your variable names (i.e., legend titles). If you would rename the columns, you would also need to update your aesthetic names in any call to `aes`. In order to circumvent this problem, you could just change the legend title positions.

```r
library(ggplot2)
## I made the example a bit more interesting with different lengths of your unique aesthetics
df <- data.frame(somethingthatisverylong = c("aaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"), 
                 col2 = c("b", "d", "e"), 
                 col3 = 1:6, 
                 col4 = 1:6)

pad_legend <- function(df, aes1, aes2){
  unq <- lapply(df[c(aes1, aes2)], unique)
  ## return each corresponding unique element
  names_v <- lapply(1:max(lengths(unq)), function(i) unname(unlist(purrr::map(unq, i))))
  ## for 
  v <- purrr::map(names_v, ~stringr::str_pad(.x, max(nchar(.x)), pad = " ", side = "right"))
  v_named<- purrr::map2(v, names_v, function(.x, .y) {
    names(.x) <- .y
    .x
  })
  v_lu <- unlist(v_named)
  ## use this vector for matched substituting 
  df[c(aes1, aes2)] <- lapply(df[c(aes1, aes2)], function(x) v_lu[x])
  df
}

df <- pad_legend(df, "somethingthatisverylong", "col2")

ggplot(df, aes(col3, col4, color = somethingthatisverylong, shape = col2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.box = "vertical", 
        legend.box.just = "left", 
        ## use a monospace font
        legend.text = element_text(family = "Courier")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title.position="top"), 
         shape = guide_legend(title.position="top"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! Your custom function is useful! I thought there could be a "hidden" package that can do legend customisation (like keys and titles alignment), but seems like there's none. And yes this is a special case because I'm improving a single graph for publication reason, that's why I think I should align the legend items :) Thanks again for your very detailed suggestions!

Comment: @benson23 thanks. I think if it is indeed only one figure, the arguably easiest would be to do indeed just your hack. Instead of manually typing out all spaces, you could also just make a long string of spaces, e.g. with `paste(rep(“ “, n), collapse = “”)`